# Cannot run .cmd from PowerShell: access denied

Tags: powershell, cmd, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run a `.cmd` script from an interactive PowerShell session. I can invoke the script from `cmd.exe`, but from PS I get:

```
PS C:\path\to\my\script> .\some_script.cmd
Fehler beim Ausführen des Programms "some_script.cmd": Zugriff verweigertIn Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ .\some_script.cmd
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ .\some_script.cmd
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

(The German part means "Error while executing program ...: Access denied")

I tried from both within VS code, and a regular PS prompt. I have all the neccessary access rights to the file in question. I know you have to enable execution of PS scripts, but shouldn't it run a .cmd script just like it would open a .docx file (by calling the default verb)? I tried to use `Invoke-Item` to do so explicitly, but got the same error. How can I run this script, preferably just by `.\some_script.cmd` without any contortions or wrappers?

Comment: Does this need to be run from an elevated prompt or does that not matter?

Comment: @Matt no, it should work from a regular prompt

Comment: If you haven't done so already, download `procmon` from sysinternals. Run it (start capture <ctrl-e>), execute your script, stop it (<ctrl-e>) and select tools -> Count Occurrences -> Column Result -> Count and filter on errors.It should shed some light on the situation.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure why that's not working for you.  It works fine on my machine.  It's possible the file association for .cmd files is missing.

As a workaround, you can call the command prompt shell directly:

```
cmd.exe /C .\some_script.cmd
```

Or, failing that:

```
& "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /C .\some_script.cmd
```

Or, failing *that*:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "/C",".\some_script.cmd"
```

Comment: It's very wierd, `cmd /C script.cmd` works and I guess I can live with that.

Comment: i experience this problem. this workaround works but it sucks that i need it. i wish someone understood & could make this operating system work.